# SQLite Errors and Exits (after first result) when running IF statement inside FOR loop

Tags: python, sqlite, scrapy

I built a scrapy spider to run through a job site and return all jobs I'm qualified for so I don't have to scroll through them every day.

I'm parsing the json correctly:

```
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body)
        for item in jsonresponse:
            yield{
                'id':item['id'],
                'date':item['date'],
                'company':item['company'],
                'position':item['position'],
                'description':item['description'],
                'url':item['url'],
                }
```

And I set up a function to take whatever .csv file I save the results as, create a new one as a backup, then create a SQLite db to dump results into:

```
    def close(self, reason):
        csv_file = max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)

        with open(csv_file) as input, open('jobs2.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output)
            for row in csv.reader(input):
                if any(field.strip() for field in row):
                    writer.writerow(row)


        db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
        csv_data = csv.DictReader(open('jobs.csv'))
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE jobs_table(date TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                                               id TEXT,
                                               company TEXT, 
                                               position TEXT,
                                               description TEXT,
                                               url TEXT)
                    ''')


        db.commit()
        print('')
        print('DB CREATED')
        print('')
```

Then, I'm defining a list of "skills" to check against each row in the .csv file to see if I'm qualified for the position:

````
    # skills = {'python'}
    skills = ('python')

    for row in csv_data:
        if skills in row.get('description').lower():
            print('Job Match!')
            print('')
            print('')
            print(row)
            print('')
            print('')```
````

And this is where I run into issues. It prints that there is a Match, and it prints the OrderedDict for the FIRST result:

````
2019-06-18 14:59:56 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (309 items) in: jobs.csv```


DB CREATED


Job Match!


OrderedDict([('id', '73345'), ('date', '2019-06-11T14:16:33-07:00'), ('company', 'JBS Custom Software Solutions'), ('position', 'Full Stack Developer'), ('description', 'JBS Full-Stack Developer (Python, JavaScript, PostgreSQL)Required; 3+ years working with Python&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 3+ years working with JavaScript; Strong knowledge of modern JavaScript development practices; Strong computer science skills'), ('url', 'https://entrenous.com/jobs/73472')])```
````

Then, problems occur when I try to run cur.execute() to INSERT rows INTO my "jobs_table". Here's what I've tried (COMMANDS) and what it's kicked back (ERROR):

COMMAND:
`cur.execute('INSERT INTO jobs_table(date, id, company, position, description, url) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)`

ERROR:
`(sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error)`

COMMAND:
`cur.execute('INSERT INTO jobs_table(date, id, company, position, description, url) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', row)`

ERROR: 
`(sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Binding 1 has no name, but you supplied a dictionary (which has only names).)`

COMMAND:
`cur.execute("INSERT INTO jobs_table(date, id, company, position, description, url) VALUES(date, id, company, position, description, url)", row)`

ERROR: 
`(sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: date)`

COMMAND:
`cur.execute("INSERT INTO jobs_table(date, id, company, position, description, url) VALUES(:date, :id, :company, :position, :description, :url)", row)`

ERROR: 
`(sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: jobs_table.date)`

COMMAND:
`cur.execute("INSERT INTO jobs_table(date, id, company, position, description, url) VALUES('date', 'id', 'company', 'position', 'description', 'url')", row)`

ERROR: 
`(sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: jobs_table.date)`

I'm wrapping it up with a simple commit, close and a print function to let me know everything's fine and I can go back to bed, but as things stand, I can't go back to bed.

```
        db.commit()
        db.close()
        print("JOBS IMPORTED!")
```

I posted a similar question earlier, but wasn't nearly as clear with what I wanted to gain from posting here, so here's what I want:
**I want to be able to save only jobs with ["descriptions"] that contain my ["skills"].** 
The rest of them are useless to me.

***Is there anyone out there who can help me with this?***

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error:  (sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: jobs_table.date)

Make sure you're INSERTING things in the right order...
Moving on!